# foreach invalid argument supplied and mysql fetch array issue

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code which i use to print some fields from the database.

My problem is that i get this error about foreach invalid argument supplied and a mysql fetch array problem.

The code is this:

```
foreach( $checked1 as $key => $value){
    echo "<th> $value </th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Where `$checked1` is an array

```
$checked1 = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

What's the problem here?

The whole code:

```
    <?php

echo "<div id='table-3'>"; 
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $checked1 = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);

    }
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','user','passwd');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess");
    echo "<table >";
    echo "<thead><tr>";
    if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])){
 foreach( $checked1 as $key => $value){
    echo "<th> $value </th>";
    }
    echo "</tr></thead>";

    } else {
echo "Checkbox is not an array.";
}



   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
foreach($checked1 as $key => $value){
if($value == 'photo'){
 echo "<td> <img src=foto/photo1/".$row[$value] . "></td>";

}   else if($value == 'photo2'){
echo "<td><img src=foto/photo2/".$row[$value] . "></td></td>";

}
else if( $value == 'photo2' && $value == 'photo'){
    echo "<td> <img src=foto/photo1/".$row[$value] . "></td>";
    echo "<td><img src=foto/photo2/".$row[$value] . "></td></td>";
}
else{

    echo "<td>" . $row[$value] . "</td>";
}
}echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The *exact* error message(s) would be more useful. And `$result` is probably not a valid MySQL resource.

Comment: Can you please see my updated code?

Comment: @LaMyse I think I might have overwritten your update with my edit. Please try again.

Comment: Could you do `var_dump($checked1);` and `var_dump($result);` just before the snippet you gave us, and post the result here or on pastebin.com ?

Comment: @LaMyse: If you don't provide any debugging errors from PHP we won't be able to help you further.

Comment: Hey Alex, i just did it, and the reult for both of them is NULL

Comment: I updated the code, i inserted the whole code, the checkbox value is just a  input form..

Answer (score 1):

Either `$_POST['checkbox']` is not defined (no checkbox checked while sending form) or is not an array (input name does not contain `[]` in the end);

You should always check if variable contain what you want before performing any operation on it, ex:

```
if(is_array($checked1)){
    foreach( ... ){  
    }
}

$result = mysql_query(' ... ');

if(!$result){
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Yes, i've checked it, when i try to submit the code everything works fine, but when i do a print of the web page, there come this errors not the results.. which happens to be strange...

Comment: What do you mean by `print of webpage`? Are you using some function to display the page, and errors occur in this function?

Comment: Yes, i'm using an online web printer as pdf, it worked on all pages, even on this with the problem, is just that here it prints out errors..

Comment: You have to show us more code, where `$checked1` is still an array, where you are trying to iterate on it with foreach. You may have changed scope to where this variable is undefined.

Comment: just use the check if it is an array/contains any data, probably if you print it, it doesn't. So make sure to set either no or an alternative `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

What is your $_POST['checkbox'] called in your HTML form? It should be something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" />
```

Check to make sure your checkbox values are coming through as arrays. Do the following:

```
if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])){
// contiue with foreach...
} else {
echo "Checkbox is not an array.";
}
```

Comment: it is an array.., i just checked it!